# Inventario: actualizar stock segun la cantidad que el usuario ingrese en un input en razor

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

Estoy haciendo un sistema de inventarios, donde tengo que agregar o quitar existencias de un producto. Actualmente tengo una tabla `producto` donde guardo los datos del producto (así como la cantidad que tengo en stock), y una tabla `movimientoEntrada`, donde registro una entrada, el producto que entra y la cantidad de ese producto que entra por medio de un TextBox.

Estoy usando entity framework para hacer la conexión con la base y use scaffolding para hacer unas interfaces, el problema es que no encuentro una forma de poder sumar la cantidad de producto que entra especificada en el input de la vista del `movimientoEntrada`, o en su defecto sumar los valores de las tablas para poder actualizar el stock que tengo, estos son mis códigos:

Clase/Tabla movimientoEntrada:

```
public class MovimientoEntrada
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductosId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductosId")]
    public virtual Productos Producto { get; set; }
    public List<Productos> ProductoCollection { get; set; }

    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

clase/tabla Productos:

```
public class Productos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CodigoBarras { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Código en controlador con el que genero un nuevo `movimientoEntrada`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductosId,Cantidad")] MovimientoEntrada movimientoEntrada)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MovimientoEntradas.Add(movimientoEntrada);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ProductosId = new SelectList(db.Productos, "Id", "Nombre",  movimientoEntrada.ProductosId);
        return View(movimientoEntrada);
    }
```

Código de mi vista de `movimientoEntrada`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MovimientoEntrada</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductosId, "ProductosId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ProductosId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductosId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cantidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cantidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```